# What does the second set of pranthesis in javascript function call?

Tags: javascript, closures

In this example , what does the second set pf parenthesis do in foo()()?

```
function foo() {
var bar = "bar";

  return function (){
    console.log(bar);
  };

}

function bam() {
  foo()(); // <--------------
}

bam ();
```

I was trying to learn about closure that i came across this example where ()() is used which confuses me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do the second set of parenthesis do in `foo()()`?

The first parenthesis are invoking the `foo` function. The second set of parenthesis invoke the anonymous function that `foo` returns.

In other words, the second set of parenthesis invoke the following anonymous function:

```
function() {
  console.log(bar);
}
```

The function `foo` returns is essentially evaluated like this:

```
function bam() {
  (function() {
    console.log("bar");
  })();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the function `foo` returns a function:

```
function foo() {
    var bar = "bar";
    return function () { // here
        console.log(bar);
    };
}
```

So when you call `foo()` it will return a function, wich you can call imediatly with `foo()()`